# Email Recepient Limit

Tags: smtp, office365

I was wondering whether there is a recipient limit imposed on a single email? I mean how many email addresses can a single email have. I particularly interested in the BCC.

I currently use SMTP over an Office365 Outlook service.

Comment: It varies by your providers account.  Off the top of my head, I believe the limit on my office365 account is 50.  There can also be sending limits imposed per hour or per day.  Free accounts to to be more limited than pay accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/exchange-online-limits%28EXCHG.150%29.aspx#RecipientLimits);

> These limits are applied to messages, senders, or recipients to combat
>   spam and mass-mailing worms or viruses.

[[image: Picture]
<sup>Click for full size image</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V6xH.jpg)